# How do I paint clouds?

Tags: algorithm, canvas, svg, vector-graphics

I need an algorithm to paint clouds, or cloud like shapes. Obviously, I wouldn't want them all to be similar.
What should I use to generate the relevant series of X,Y coordinates to paint the clouds?
I am going to implement this either in SVG or Canvas

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - may be I am not using the right words. First few pages on google where on cloud computing and Amazon and the like search results.

Comment: what's wrong with this place? how has this question been up for an hour and no one has made a Bob Ross reference?

Comment: @Brahma Ghosh, fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177121/how-do-i-paint-clouds/3177352#3177352

Comment: This is hands down the best title for a question. Ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the SVG feTurbulence filter primitive to generate Perlin noise, which can be used to create cloud-like textures.

Some help and examples:

- http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#feTurbulence
- http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Filters
- http://pilatinfo.org/english/filters/index.htm

The [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) vector graphics editor also has a big collection of predefined svg filters, see [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/some-inkscape-filters.svg) for an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/some-inkscape-filters.svg) using just a few of them on some text. The "noise fill" one is using feTurbulence, and is probably quite easy to tweak. Inkscape also has a GUI for tweaking the parameters of each filter, select any shape, then select "Filter > Filter Editor..." in the menus.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on exactly what kind of clouds you're going for. You can try [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) which is quite popular with game developers.

Comment: I need to implement it in SVG

Comment: How do I tell it when to start closing the shape? Do I have to do it manually, or is there an equation for that too?

Answer (score 3):

To give your trees friends, paint many happy little accidents.

I recommend canvas - you can get crazy with the brush!

I'd like to wish you happy painting, and God bless my friend.

Answer (score 2):

here is an example of Perlin noise done with silverlight: http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2009/05/oscar-algorithm-silverlight-real-time.html

it's probably something you can use and/or adapt.

Answer (score 0):

If implementing in canvas and you want the puffy cloud shape not the noise kind, I would say draw a rectangle of some random length then add circles of varying sizes first to the sides then to the top to get the cloud effect.  You would have to do some math to make sure the clouds did not show below the rectangle and that the top of the rectangle did not have any straight sections.  But it shouldn't be to hard to implement in canvas.

Comment: or just merging many circles - so you won't get troubles with straight sections

Answer (score 0):

this code makes a bunch of circles in an array of colors maybe it will help you with the clouds

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
      for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++)
      {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('c1').getContext('2d');
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,' + Math.floor(255 - 42.5 * i) + ',' + 
        Math.floor(255 - 42.5 * j) + ')';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(40 + j * 25, 40 + i * 25, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.stroke();
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a cluster of bubbles (circles or horizontal ellipses) and take the union of the shapes for each cloud.